# char[] with duplicate value after strcpy

Tags: c, char, duplicates, strcpy

I have a struct with two char array variables(id and id_partner_expected) and when i use the strcpy on second array the first array is changed also. I tried everything i know, but without expected result :(

```
#define SIZE_CLIENT_ID 15

struct client_infos {
    char addr[INET_ADDRSTRLEN];
    int socket;
    char id[SIZE_CLIENT_ID];
    char id_partner_expected[SIZE_CLIENT_ID];
    struct client_infos* partner;
};

char buffer_received[MAX_CLIENT_IO];


while ((len_received = recv(c->socket, buffer_received, MAX_CLIENT_IO, 0)) > 0) {

    if (strlen(c->id) == 0) {
        //First step: Identify the client

        strcpy(c->id, buffer_received); // FIRST LOOP

    } else if (strlen(c->id_partner_expected) == 0) {
        //Second step: Identify/Connect the partner


        strcpy(c->id_partner_expected, buffer_received); // SECOND LOOP

    }

    printf("Received %d bytes from client %s, with id %s", len_received, c->addr, c->id);
    printf("%d\n", strlen(c->id));//STRCPY DUPLICATING CONTENT OF C->ID ???!!!
}
```

Result:

1º loop:

Received 15 bytes from client 0.0.0.0, with id 0000654987321
  15

2º loop:

Received 15 bytes from client 0.0.0.0, with id 0000654987321
  6544sssss5555
  30

But the result expected is:

2º loop:

Received 15 bytes from client 0.0.0.0, with id 0000654987321
  15

Original source here:
https://github.com/fernandobatels/blitz-p2p-bridge/blob/master/src/api.h 
https://github.com/fernandobatels/blitz-p2p-bridge/blob/master/src/api.c

Thanks for all help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

C strings are zero terminated. Strings you receive from the network are, apparently, not. You need to zero-terminate the strings after receiving the data:

```
...
while ((len_received = recv(c->socket, buffer_received, MAX_CLIENT_IO, 0)) > 0) {
    buffer_received[len_received] = 0; // add this line
    if (strlen(c->id) == 0) {
    ...
```

Also note that as your maximum ID length (and the maximum amount of data received from the network) is 15, you need to extend your arrays by one character to make room for the terminating zero:

```
struct client_infos {
    char addr[INET_ADDRSTRLEN];
    int socket;
    char id[SIZE_CLIENT_ID + 1];
    char id_partner_expected[SIZE_CLIENT_ID + 1];
    struct client_infos* partner;
}

char buffer_received[MAX_CLIENT_ID + 1];
```

Comment: Worked perfectly! Thanks you so much.